# Launch LibGDX screen from Android Activity

Tags: java, android, libgdx

- **Context:** I'm currently developing an Android Application containing different mini-games related to randomness, one of its requirements is to share the seed used by the pseudo-random generator to generate an initial state of the game. Also I'm using some Android services and permissions, like Internet and camera to share the seed (using QR for example).
- **Question:** I want to know if its possible to launch a LibGDX screen from an Android Activity and how, with an example if possible. I tried to find examples, but there are answers from like four years ago, and some things have changed. If isn't possible, I need to know if I can do the opposite (create a LibGDX game from the scratch, recreating the menu and all the stuff) without losing access to the services and permissions, to launch the camera to recognize QR for example.
- I asked the same question in the LibGDX forum two weeks ago, but nobody answered. If its too complicated, do you have any suggestion? like changing framework or something else? I've been thinking switch to Unity, because the documentation, but I'm not sure. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From Any Native Activity to LibGDX Activity :**

Yes, It is possible to launch a LibGDX screen from an Android `Activity`.

`AndroidLauncher.java` is a launcher `Activity` of LibGDX and In Android you can move from one activity to another using `Intent`.

```
intent = new Intent(this, AndroidLauncher.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**From LibGDX Screen to any Native Activity :**

Any Screen of LibGDX is nothing more than a View of `AndroidLauncher` activity. You need to use [interfacing](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) to call android specific APIs and move to another Activity.

<sub>You need to maintain OpenGL Context Loss.</sub>

Comment: But, how do I set the project to use LibGDX? should I add the libraries to build.gradle and manually create the folders (I think this should have been my question haha), or do you recomend me initiate a new LibGDX project modifiying the things I already have

Comment: Yes, you've to use libgdx libraries if you want to LibGDX in your project , Either inject dependency using gradle or manually you can compile jars and native files in your project.